# The "No" option in my JOptionPane is not working properly. Why?

Tags: mysql, netbeans

I have created a program for adding items to an inventory connected to a MySQL database. When the user clicks "Add" a JOptionPane will come up asking them if they wish to add the item to the database. The coding seems correct but when I click on "No" it still adds the item to the database. Here is the code:

```
int dialogButton = JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION;
JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog (null, "Are you sure you want to add this item?",null, dialogButton);
if(dialogButton == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) 
{
    Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();
    stmt.executeUpdate(query);

    if(dialogButton == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) 
    {
        remove(dialogButton);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the `if(dialogButton == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION)` is inside the `if(dialogButton == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)` block. It should never execute. Try moving it just outside of that block.

```
if(dialogButton == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) 
{
    Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();
    stmt.executeUpdate(query);
}
else if(dialogButton == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) 
{
    remove(dialogButton);
}
```

Secondly, `JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog` returns an integer, representing the button that was pressed. You need to check whether this result is `JOptionPane.YES_OPTION` or `JOptionPane.NO_OPTION`. You should have:

```
int dialogButton = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog (null, "Are you sure you want to add this item?",null, 0);
```

Comment: I tried using integers and it's still doing the same thing

Comment: As @JHobern said, we should create an int variable `dialogResult` receiving the returned value from the dialogue, and then play with this variable within the conditions instead of the `dialogButton`.